# Identifying normalisation form

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization

Here's the relational schemas i have:

```
OfficeCustomer(office, customer, employee)

office, customer -> employee
employee -> office
```

This is my current analysis,

Minimal super key is (**office**, **customer**), non-key attribute **employee** is fully functional dependent on (**office**, **customer**) only. So this should be minimally 2NF.

Is (**office**, **customer**) -> **employee** -> **office** considered transitive?

Need help to confirm the highest normal form for the above relational table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one candidate key.

That's the key to the rest of the answer.

(I'm assuming this is homework, so I won't spoonfeed any more and let you first think it through.)